# In Android can we use style and background in Textview or Edittext

Tags: android, android-layout

when I am trying to add background and style but style effects are not shown in text view...

```
<TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvModelYearMax"
                                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/transparent_square"
                                android:elevation="@dimen/normal_elevation"
                                android:text="2018" ></TextView>
```

Comment: I think maybe it is because you are trying to apply a style used for Spinner in TextView.

Comment: you can add this background into style tage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this approach. Set background style in relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_square">

         <Spinner
             android:id="@+id/tvModelYearMax"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```